# How to launch ball in an arc between two points?

Tags: construct-2

How do I launch a ball in an arc from one place to another? I am using Construct 2 personal but am not familiar with the program, can anyone help?

Comment: You should probably change title to something meaningful as "help beginner" is not very descriptive. I'd also suggest expanding your question to make clear what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

In Construct 2, sprites can have "Behaviours". You might want to add the Bullet and Gravity behaviour to your ball, and tweak the parameters so that the Ball fires at the angle you want it to, and then the Gravity behaviour will cause it to fall to the bottom of the screen. You could also set the speed of the Ball's movement from user-input.

Or do you want to the ball to land at a specific point?

Comment: This isn't the place for back and forth discussion as part of your answer. If you're unable to provide a complete answer with the information provided, don't post an answer.

Comment: My answer gives an solution to what the question asked fine and I only queried if he is looking for a specific situation.

Comment: @MidnightPacific To some extent, correspondence about improving/specifying the question belongs in the question comments. It's still possible to write an answer by stating the assumptions made and later improve or remove it to fit the question as it improves.